# in google bar chart i need the numbers in vaxis to be shown as comma separated values?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

```
var options = {
            width: 700,
            height: 400,
            interpolateNulls: true,
            title: title_val,
            hAxis: {
                title: haxis_title
            },
            vAxis: {
                title: vaxis_title,
                logscale: vaxis_logscale,
                format: '$',
            },
            legend: {
                position: 'right'
            }
        };
    }
    charttrend.draw(dataTable, options);
```

Comment: will you please clarify, provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to format your data using this,

```
format: 'decimal' // displays numbers with thousands separators
```

or if its currency then

```
format: 'currency'
```

or something like this

```
format:'#,###%'
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#number-formats

Comment: Is it possible to  have it displaying numbers in format like  '$10,000' ?